# Calculating the area of a polygon with equal sides inscribed in a circle with radius r.

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

Calculating the area of a polygon with equal sides inscribed in a circle with radius r.By dividing the polygon into congruent triangles with central angle, show that:
$$A_{n} = \frac{1}{2}n r^2 \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right),$$

How can I use Darboux sums to do so, could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Why do you want to use Darboux sums for this? This a simple geometric problem, you need to figure out how to calculate the area of one of those congruent triangles.

Comment: because we have taken only this lesson and a theorem for calculating the integration using limit (in which we partition our interval into n regular intervals), so I assumed that we have to use this @Thomas

Comment: @Thomas  could you please see this question also if you have time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674910/the-difference-between-calculating-the-upper-darboux-sum-for-a-function-using-n

Comment: I have to admit I do not even understand what is asked in your other question. Are you sure the formula for the area of the triangle is correct? I think the factor $\pi$ in front of the $\sin$ is wrong.

Comment: I expect that you are supposed to do this the simple way, and later see it as a sum which can help to find the area of the circle as a limit.

Comment: I am asking what  is the difference between the formula for calculating  Darboux sums if I am going to divide my interval to n equal subintervals and Darboux sums if I am going to divide my interval to 3n equal subintervals?@Thomas

Comment: @MarkBennet  could you say a bit more details about your idea because it seems as if what I am searching Mark?

Comment: @Thomas yes I am sure the formula for the area of the triangle is correct.

Comment: One way of thinking about an integral is that you want to divide up the area/volume etc which is your target into bits which are easy to compute (without leaving too much gap or allowing too much overlap). It is the bit in brackets which is the source of most of the challenge in getting a good definition, partly because boundaries are not always well-behaved. Here the simple pieces are triangles, and you know the area of a triangle, so you just use that as suggested by @Thomas. Then you worry about the limit and the gaps afterwards.

Comment: no, the formula is incorrect. The factor $\pi$ is definitely wrong.

Comment: why $\pi$ is definitely incorrect ?@Thomas

Comment: If $A_n$ represents the area of the regular $n$-sided inscribed polygon, then I believe you mis-copied the formula. The first $\pi$ should have been something else, something that may have resembled $\pi$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales   may be my professor had made this slight mistake ....... it was a question in a quiz.

Comment: The correct equation is $A_{n} = \frac{1}{2}n r^2 \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right),$

Comment: And the question has rest which is: show that $$\lim_{n \larrow \infty} A_{n} = \pi r^2$$ @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: I have corrected the error in the above equation ...... Thank you @Thomas

Comment: I have corrected the error in the above equation ...... Thank you @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: For the limit you will have to use the fact that if $\theta\approx0$ then $\sin\theta\approx\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you find the area of the triangle in this diagram? Do you see how to use it to find the area of an $n$-sided regular polygon inscribed in the circle?

You will need the identity

$$\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
[image: sector of circle]

Comment: "Do you see how to use it to find the area of an n-sided regular polygon inscribed in the circle?" No I do not see ..... could you explain for me please?

Comment: why you give the side drawn in your picture the length $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, why specially that side?

Comment: That is the measure of the central angle. If you divide $2\pi$ by $n$ you get that angle.

Comment: I followed your hint and did the computation to get the answer $$A=nr^2\sin\frac{\pi}n\cos\frac{\pi}n.$$ Can I ask if this is correct? I think it is, because I took $n \to \infty$ and computed the limit, using l'Hopital's rule along the way (and pretending that $n$ was a continuous variable for the moment to use the rule), to get the area of the circle $$A=\pi r^2.$$

Comment: @cookie Yes, that i correct. You could also use the fact that $\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\cos\frac{\pi}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$ to simplify the formula for $A$, but that is not absolutely necessary.