# Find the area of the garden planted with flowers.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

A garden is shaped in the form of a regular heptagon (seven-sided), $MNSRQPO$.
A circle with centre $T$ and radius $25\ \text{m}$ circumscribes the heptagon as shown in the diagram below. The area of $\triangle MSQ$ is left for a children's playground, and the rest of the garden is planted with flowers. Find the area of the garden planted with flowers.

[image]

---

I am confused about this question. Can you please give me the hint.
Do I need to find first area of a circle and then subtract the area of a triangle from it?

Comment: The is no need to calculate the area of any part of the circle. Are you familiar with this formula for the area of a triangle?
$$A=\frac12ab\sin C$$

Comment: @player3236 Yes, I know. But in this question, we do not have 'a' ,'b' (lengths of sides of a triangle) and also the angle C. How we can find these?

Comment: Connect all the vertices of the heptagon to the centre $T$. Then you know the side lengths and the angles in the centre.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to find the area of the triangle and subtract it from the area of heptagon.

Area of heptagon is pretty straightforward i.e. $\pi r^2$

And for area of triangle $MSQ$, consider line $TM $ and $TS$ whose length are nothing but the circle's radius. And the triangle formed will be $MTS$ and the angle formed at $T$ will be equal to 2 parts of the $360$ degree divided into 7 equal parts, because between $TM$ and $TS$ 2 sides of 7 sided quadrilateral is included, so the angle at $T$ will be $\frac{360}{7} * 2$. And after that, you should be able to find the length of the side $MS$ of triangle $MSQ$ by making a perpendicular bisector at angle $T$ formed by triangle $MTS$.

Likewise you can find all the sides of the isosceles triangle and then its area.

Hope you get my hint. Try reading it one more time, if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Read the question. You don't need the area of the circle.

Comment: I can share the explanation in the page too and upload it. But I think, you should at first try on your own and do a bit of brain storming.

Comment: @player3236 This was just my way of solving it, you might even be able to do it without the circle's area too. Method differs from person to person.

Comment: I'm more curious as to how the area of the circle could come into play, seeing that the shape of the garden is a heptagon.

Comment: Oh okay, my bad. I thought that the circle is the garden, but it is the heptagon that is garden. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: So, it should be heptagon's area instead of circle's area, right?

Comment: @JeetKaria can you please explain how to find the area of a triangle MSQ. I tried it but couldn't found it.

Comment: @JeetKaria I tried it. But I am confused about the area of the triangle MSQ. How can we find it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The side $a$ of a regular $n$-sided polygon, given radius of its circumscribed circle $r$ is $$a=2r\sin\left(\frac{π}{n}\right)\tag 1$$
Also, the area of polygon is $$A=\frac{1}{2}nr^2\sin\left(\frac{2π}{n}\right)\tag 2$$
Refer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2675082) post.

---

Now, to find the area of $\triangle MSQ$, we need the base $MQ$ and height $SA$. $A$ is the point of intersection of $MQ$ with the $x$-axis.

Knowing that any two consecutive vertices of heptagon subtend an angle of $\frac{2π}{7}$ at the center of the circumscribed circle (here the origin $T$), we get $\angle MTA=\frac{3π}{7}$.

$$\begin{align}\text{Area}(\triangle MSQ)&=\frac{1}{2}MQ\cdot SA\\ 
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\cdot 25\sin\frac{3π}{7}\right)\left(25+25\cos\frac{3π}{7}\right)\\
&=625\sin\frac{3π}{7}\left(1+\cos\frac{3π}{7}\right)\tag 3\end{align}$$

> From $(2)$ and $(3)$ the area of the garden planted with flowers is $$1875\sin\left(\frac{2π}{7}\right)-625\sin\left(\frac{π}{7}\right)\ \text{m}^2$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the area of Triangle MSQ, we need the measure of two sides and one included angle.

MS = SQ, so if we just find the measure of one, we'll have two sides.

The angle MSQ can be found using circle theorems.

> **Angle MTS** = 2(360/7) because it is formed by two central angles.
>  **Angle MQS** = 1/2 of Angle MTS because an angle subtended by a chord at the centre is twice the angle subtended at the circumference.
>  **Angle SMQ** = Angle MQS = 360/7 (because the triangle MSQ is isosceles - base angles are equal)
>  **Angle MSQ** = 180 - 2(360/7)

To find MS, first try finding MN, then use the isosceles triangle MNS to find MS.

[Worked solution attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkCyI.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.